# How to check if two installed applications use the same shared user label?

Tags: android

How can I scan installed applications on an android device and to find if any two applications are using the same `SharedUserLabel`? And then list those applications?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use label string and add it to a map and then sort as you wish

```
   List<PackageInfo> pkgs = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (int i=0; i<pkgs.size(); i++) {
            MyPackageInfo info = new MyPackageInfo();
            info.info = pkgs.get(i);

            if(info.sharedUserLabel != 0) {
             // you can use label to get the label
                    CharSequence label = pm.getText(name,
                            info.sharedUserLabel, info.applicationInfo);
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Errr... something like this... might not be a perfect solution

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    packageInfo.sharedUserLabel()
}
```

.. See this link for [packageinfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) basically list all the installed packages then loop through them to see which one has the shareduserlabel that your interested in

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try and let you know